Optimized on-disk data structure for search with minimal random accesses
I have a huge file (~16TB) that contains a list of 8-byte keys mapped to 8-byte values. (2^40 pairs, 16 bytes each).
I would now like to optimize the file so that I can search it efficiently. I have currently sorted the file and perform a binary search on it. This completes in 30 reads, but these reads are highly distributed around the file, especially at the start.
I am aware I can load the entire binary search partition that's left after 10 steps into 16GB memory and continue the search there. However, I only have a negligible amount of memory available, so this isn't an option.
Is there a way to arrange the data on disk so that the accesses required to search the file are close together from the start? This would allow me to load an entire "range" of values that need to be read into memory, to reduce the number of read calls in total, and reduce the number of random accesses.
After initial construction, the file never changes, so insertion and deletion is not relevant and building any kind of index is allowed to take a long time. Also, the keys are (roughly) uniformly distributed across the 2^64 space.

Could you please share a bit more information? Does this file ever change? Is insertion and deletion relevant? Are the queries to the file always key to value lookups, or also value to key?

Also, do the keys happen to be contiguous, or are they more or less randomly distributed in the space of 2^64 possible keys?

Apologies, I've added some details. Value to key lookups are not relevant.

Is this real disc (rotating memory), or SSD?

2^30 * 16 bytes / (102410241024) = 16 GB according to my calculation.

Ugh, what a mess. Sorry about that, it's 2^40 pairs, unfortunate typo.

@MichaelKay This is not final yet. I assume SSDs only have advantages, so feel free to assume SSD.

Well, with SSD the read time is going to be fairly independent of the location of a record in the file, except for caching effects. With rotating memory the seek time will play a major role.

@MichaelKay I disagree. On SSDs, random access vs linear access on block level is roughly the same, but reading 4KB from the same block on an SSD much faster than reading 4KB from many different blocks.

Yes, with SSD you still get benefits from colocation, but you don't get the other factor that you have with rotating drives where data near the centre of the file is faster to access than data near the edges.

@Frederik Is it an option to split the file into several smaller files and place them in directories matching the range of these files?

The best solution to your problem is not the arrangement of the data on the disk, but an index that can be used to look up the address of the key on the disk. Maintaining such an index can reduce the amount of read operations from 30 to 2. Bam.
A 32 bit index is best suited for your situation.
Imagine we split up the 64 bit space that your keys span into 2^32 buckets. Then, each of these buckets could hold 2^32 keys, since 2^32 * 2^32 = 2^64. However, since you only have 2^40 items in total (hopefully) uniformly distributed in the 2^64 space, each of these buckets would only need to hold 2^8 number of items in average, since 2^32 * 2^8 = 2^40. 2^8 is just 256, times 16 bytes per item yields 4 kilobytes of data per bucket that you could load with one read operation from the disk and then search those 256 items in RAM for the correct one. Surely you have 4KB memory to spare? Otherwise you must have like a pocket calculator with a petabyte-sized disk attached. If you really have no memory beyond the minimum of 16 bytes you need to store a single item, then you would still need to binary search those 256 items and you would at least be down to 9 disk reads instead of 30 (one for the index lookup and 8 for the binary search) and these would even be relatively close to each other.
So, the procedure is as follows.
First, create a hash(key) (read: hash of key) function like so:
hash(key) = take the 32 most significant bits of key

You can accomplish this by using a bit mask. Lightning fast. You will find that a bunch of your keys map to the same hash, but that's okay. Each of these hash values will be the address of a piece of information (disk_address, items) that stores 1. the address of the bucket on disk, and 2. the number of items in the same bucket (which could be more or less than 256).
Then, sort your data by key as you already have, and write your data to the disk sequentially back to back, thereby also building the index by remembering the address of every bucket on the disk and the number of data items that land in the bucket.
i = 0
while (still have data left)
{
    disk_address = writeData(data[i])
    if (index[hash(key[i])] == (0,0))
        index[hash(key[i])] = (disk_address, 1);
    else
        index[hash(key[i])] = (disk_address, index[hash(key[i])].items + 1);
    i++
}

The size of the index would be 2^32 * (64 bit for the address + 16 bit for the number of items) = 40 GB, which is a tiny amount (0.0025%) compared to the 16 TB you have, and the index can be stored on disk.
Finally, to look up the value identified by a given key:
(disk_address, items) = load_from_disk(index[hash(key)]) // disk read 1
data_items[items]
data_items = disk_read(disk_address, items * 16 bytes) // disk read 2
search_items_for_key(data_items, key)

Of course this is all just pseudo code and I leave the implementation to you. :)

Thank you very much for the answer! One question: As you said, the maximum amount of items per bucket is 2^32. However, you are using 16 bit for the number of items in your calculation of the index size. Is this just a probabilstic choice because it is exceedingly unlikely I'm gonna exceed more than 2^16 items per bucket?

Oh yes, good question. You will have 256 items in a bucket on average, which would require 8 bits for storing the number of items. But sometimes you will have more, and 16 bits is the next reasonable size that would allow you to store up to 65536 items per bucket. That will surely be enough, right? It would be prudent to analyze your data and determine the size of the largest bucket.

Gotcha, thank you! Coincidentally I already have "bit level" reads implemented (i.e "read next 14 bits as big endian uint16_t"), so I think I can use the optimal sizes for address and item count here.

Yes, you can do so and I saw that you were able to shave off 4 Gigs from the index size. You love optimizing things don't you? :) Just consider that this optimization also introduces complication. When you use the keys in a program, you will have to round up to the nearest power of two. Bit level reads from the disk certainly also come with a bit of complexity that your future self, or another person who takes over the task of maintaining this data file, will have to understand. Consider if saving those 4 GB, which is 0.00025% of the total amount of data, is worth the additional complexity.

Given that you have already sorted the file, I would think that building a simple index that's just a list containing every 1024th key from the main file would be useful. Start by doing a binary search on this index, then this will tell you which part of the main file you need to look in, and you can resume the search there. The index will be 256Mb, so it should fit in main memory.

The b-tree is a reasonable format for decreasing the number of seeks on a file.  The top few levels of the b-tree should be permanently cache-able, and would allow the random access to be limited beyond that.
Consider using sqlite or another database with an underlying b-tree implementation for performance testing, should give you an idea of effectiveness before a major commitment.
If the keys are reasonably evenly distributed, then having a search space of expected location would be reasonably effective.  Assuming the first 2 bytes of the key are 0x1023 (4131 decimal).  Then they would be in the first 6% of the file.
0x1023 / 0x10000 = 0.060303406
0x1024 / 0x10000 = 0.060304931
These two probabilistic bounds may be good enough, or you could index each starting word for an accurate key.
The size of the partial key you take is a trade off between knowing where each key resides, and the amount of space you sacrifice for the index.  The above scheme uses zero indexing space if you infer the likely location.  It uses 8 bytes per index entry, where the number of entries relates to the size of the key-prefix you use for the index.

Expanding on @Marcell 's answer, splitting the data into buckets requires finding an appropriate tradeoff between bucket size / index size and number of items in each bucket.
To aid in this, I wrote a small Python script to calculate the size of the index given a number of prefix bits for each bucket, the keyspace size, and the number of keys:
def print_bucket_info(prefix_bits_per_bucket: int, total_keyspace_bits: int = 64, total_items_bits: int = 40):
    max_item_count_bits_per_bucket = total_keyspace_bits - prefix_bits_per_bucket
    avg_item_count_bits_per_bucket = total_items_bits - prefix_bits_per_bucket
    
    # Each entry in the index must contain the index of the first item
    # and the number of items.
    bucket_size_bits = max_item_count_bits_per_bucket + total_items_bits

    index_size_bits = (2**prefix_bits_per_bucket) * bucket_size_bits
    
    # Convert the size to readable units
    units = ["B","KB","MB","GB","TB","PB"]
    out = f"{index_size_bits:.2f} b / "
    index_size_bits /= 8
    while units and index_size_bits > 1:
        out += f"{index_size_bits:.2f} {units.pop(0)} / "
        index_size_bits /= 1024
    
    print(f"Index with {prefix_bits_per_bucket} prefix bits per bucket takes up:", out[:-3])
    print(f"Average items per bucket:", 2**avg_item_count_bits_per_bucket)

print_bucket_info(prefix_bits_per_bucket=32)

It yields a slightly smaller index than @Marcell 's calculation because it uses exactly only the neccessary amount of bits per address:
$ python3 buckets.py
Index with 32 prefix bits per bucket takes up: 309237645312.00 b / 38654705664.00 B / 37748736.00 KB / 36864.00 MB / 36.00 GB
Average items per bucket: 256

